# Confusing about owner Wordpress website permission

Tags: wordpress, vps

I would like someone to clear up these confusion:
what is www-data owner?
if I have a user (administrator) on my Worpress or a plugin, then what is their identifier on the permissions? is this www-data?
when I want my user (administrator) on my Worpress or a plug-in to write on certain files then how to define the permissions?
on my VPS I see that the owner of my www files is the user of my Cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

`www-data` is a traditional name for the operating system's user which the HTTP server runs under.

User accounts for the OS are completely unrelated to Wordpress users, the details of which are stored in the database.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so what is the user (administrator) identifier on my WordPress or a plugin identifier so that I can put it as owner of my files. ot is www-data?

Comment: As I said, the OS user accounts and Wordpress user accounts are completely unrelated. If your webserver is running as www-data, then your PHP program will be (unless some serious security hardening has been done).